# aws elastcisearch authetication error and showing 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

```
/_cluster/health: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"no permissions for 
[cluster:monitor/health] and User [name=arn:aws:iam::271481610659:user/developer_2, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=null]"}],
"type":"security_exception", "reason":"no permissions for [cluster:monitor/health] and User [name=arn:aws:iam::271481610659:user/developer_2,
backend_roles=[],requestedTenant=null]"},"status":403}
```

Hi,

My aws elasticsearch was working fine but suddenly got this error. Whats wrong here .
What credentials it is saying is wrong due to new in these things i am not able to understand

Answer (score 3):

The errors says that user "developer_2" has "no permissions".
From the same message we can see that the backend roles are empty for this user - backend_roles=[].

To fix this, login using an admin use and use [Fine-grained access control settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html) to assign a backend role to the user "developer_2".